# FileUploadField constructor in wicket 6

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I have an issue with `FileUploadField` constructor. I think I traveled in time. So after migration into wicket 6 this constructor is no longer possible:

```
FileUploadField uploadField = new FileUploadField("browseFile", new Model<FileUpload>());
```

After removing `new Model<FileUpload>()` I got known error:

> Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method
>   defined for class: class pl.thetis.beans.service.TicketComplete
>   expression: browseFile

I noticed that second constructor is

```
public FileUploadField(final String id, IModel<List<FileUpload>> model)
{
    super(id, model);
}
```

Unfortunetly I have no idea how to create this.

I came up with this solution but I think its nasty one

```
List list = new LinkedList<FileUpload>(); 
FileUploadField uploadField = new FileUploadField("browseFile", new Model<FileUpload>().ofList(list));
```

If I declare list as `List<FileUpload>` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `new FileUploadField("browseFile", new ListModel<FileUpload>(yourList));`.

It uses a List now so it is possible to use HTML5 `<input type="file" multiple>`, i.e. you can upload several files at once with modern browsers.

Comment: Yeah I've read about that. Thanks for that solution, didn't know about ListModel.  It's nicer solution.